# php recognizing string as array

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have the following code

```
dd(gettype($default));
$test = substr($default,0,2);
```

*gettype* returns that the type of *$default* is *string*
The following error happens on the second line:

```
substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

How is this happening, and how can I solve it?

**edit** var_dump also returns a string as type

**edit** $default contains the following string: "1015"

**edit** complete code block

```
Form::macro('time', function ($name, $default) {
$hours = value(function () use ($default){
    echo gettype($default);
    $test = substr($default,0,2);
    $hours = ['' => $test];
    for ($hour = 0; $hour < 24; $hour++) {
        $hours[$hour] = $hour;
    }
    return $hours;
});
```

**edit** code where the macro is used

```
{{ Form::label('reservation_starthour', 'starthour') }}
{{ Form::time('starthour',$reservation->starthour) }}
```

Schema of the reservation table

```
Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
        $table->date('startdate');
        $table->date('enddate');
        $table->string('starthour');
        $table->string('endhour');
    });
```

Comment: @VeeeneX It's a built in Laravel function: var_dump and die, dd. If you `dd($default)` without the `gettype` what does it return?

Comment: Do some basic trouble shooting, Var Dump all variables to see what they're worth

Comment: `dd(gettype($default));var_dump($default);$test = substr($default,0,2);` If var_dump will be array then it means that the problem is in dd()

Comment: @VeeeneX The problem isn't in `dd()`. That function doesn't modify anything.

Comment: @TimLewis This is becoming a strange question, what do you think that can be the problem?

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: No, this is not my full code, but this shouldn't be necessary since you could just follow the types.

Comment: What is `$default` supposed to be? And what is the output when you `var_dump($default)`? Without knowing that, it's hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: put the entire code, also the line number of the error

Comment: At some point your macro is called and passed an `array` for `$default`.

Comment: that would not explain the type magically changing to array right after a type check I would think

Comment: Please show the code where you use the form macro

Comment: @ircmaxell This is the real code, nothing more, nothing less

Comment: Just to be sure, does the same error occur if you do: `{{ Form::time('starthour','foo') }}` ?

Comment: changing $reservation->starthour into 'foo' doesn't change anything. The error persists

Answer (score 1):

`gettype` returns the type of the variable as a string result and that result might be `"array"`, but it's still a string.  So the `dd` / `var_dump` shows it as a string.  Try:

```
echo gettype($default);
```

Comment: that also returns the type as string

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround, but not an explanation why the variable changed types.

```
Form::macro('time', function ($name, $default) {
$hours = ['' => substr(strval((int)$default),0,2)];
for ($hour = 0; $hour < 24; $hour++) {
    $hours[$hour] = $hour;
}

$minutes = ['' => substr(strval((int)$default),2)];
for ($minute = 0; $minute < 60; $minute += 15) {
    $minutes[$minute] = $minute;
}
return
    Form::select($name . '[hours]', $hours) .
    Form::select($name . '[minutes]', $minutes);
});
```

I cast the string/array to an int, get the string value, and then I could get the substring value.

I will leave this question open so someone can maybe shed some light on why the types changed.

**additional information**

Every function requiring a string as input, stated that $default was an array. Every function requiring an array as input, stated that $default was a string.